# AngularJs: How to return error message from javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, html

For custom form validation I created directives and checking whether input is valid or not.
In some cases there are multiple errors possible, and I do not want to write too many ng-messsage statement in html.

Whether I want there is one place in html and error will be return from javascript.

```
function strongSecret() {
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            require: 'ngModel',
            link: function (scope, element, attr, ctrl) {

                // please note you can name your function & argument anything you like
                function customValidator(ngModelValue) {

                    // check if contains uppercase
                    // if it does contain uppercase, set our custom `uppercaseValidator` to valid/true
                    // otherwise set it to non-valid/false
                    if (/[A-Z]/.test(ngModelValue)) {
                        ctrl.$setValidity('uppercaseValidator', true);
                    } else {
                        ctrl.$setValidity('uppercaseValidator', false);
                    }

                    // check if contains number
                    // if it does contain number, set our custom `numberValidator`  to valid/true
                    // otherwise set it to non-valid/false
                    if (/[0-9]/.test(ngModelValue)) {
                        ctrl.$setValidity('numberValidator', true);
                    } else {
                        ctrl.$setValidity('numberValidator', false);
                    }

                    // check if the length of our input is exactly 6 characters
                    // if it is 6, set our custom `sixCharactersValidator` to valid/true
                    // othwise set it to non-valid/false
                    if (ngModelValue.length === 6) {
                        ctrl.$setValidity('sixCharactersValidator', true);
                    } else {
                        ctrl.$setValidity('sixCharactersValidator', false);
                    }

                    // we need to return our ngModelValue, to be displayed to the user(value of the input)
                    return ngModelValue;
                }

                // we need to add our customValidator function to an array of other(build-in or custom) functions
                // I have not notice any performance issues, but it would be worth investigating how much
                // effect does this have on the performance of the app
                ctrl.$parsers.push(customValidator);

            }
      }
  }
```

I am looking something like, is there any set-message method or similar for particular error in angular.

Answer (score 0):

You may be looking for `console.log()`. `console.log()` is useful for debugging, just put the output inside the parenthesis. To view the output, open up the debugger tools by:

1. Right click anywhere, click "Inspect Element"
2. Press F12

Then find the section that says "Console". Your code will output to there.

Comment: I am not looking for console log. I want one commn ng-message statement with dynamic text message in html. error message should get set in angularjs. ex < div ng-message> {{text}}</div>